# adb change developer settings options programmatically

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso

How to change *Do not keep activities* in espresso testing? I need to know the name of this command in adb. How can I access all available developer settings commands from adb?

I need something like following commands;

```
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0");
```

or

```
$ adb shell settings put global wifi_on 0
```

Comment: If the answer below is correct you should select the check mark icon next to the answer to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use:

```
adb shell settings put global always_finish_activities 1
```

To activate the setting and `0` to disable it.

You can find an official list of other available settings for android [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html).

Comment: Thanks that's what I need. Is there any reference or command that shows full list of available setting commands?

Comment: I added a link to the other available settings.
If my answer helped you, please also accept it as an answer :)

Comment: As you can see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076039/adb-command-toggles-dont-keep-activities-developer-options-setting-but-it-has-n, for the don't keep activities setting, although the setting change, the behavior does not

Answer (score 11):

Following commands will list all available settings:

- adb shell settings list system
- adb shell settings list global
- adb shell settings list secure

```
$ adb shell settings 
Settings provider (settings) commands:
  help
      Print this help text.
  get [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY
      Retrieve the current value of KEY.
  put [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY VALUE [TAG] [default]
      Change the contents of KEY to VALUE.
      TAG to associate with the setting.
      {default} to set as the default, case-insensitive only for global/secure namespace
  delete [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY
      Delete the entry for KEY.
  reset [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE {PACKAGE_NAME | RESET_MODE}
      Reset the global/secure table for a package with mode.
      RESET_MODE is one of {untrusted_defaults, untrusted_clear, trusted_defaults}, case-insensitive
  list [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE
      Print all defined keys.
      NAMESPACE is one of {system, secure, global}, case-insensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

For rooted device you can run two command

1. to change settings preference run below command

   adb shell settings put system system_locales fr-CA

This command will change locale but require reboot

2. to change system properties run below command

   adb shell
   setprop persist.sys.locale fr-CA;stop;sleep 5;start

this will restart your device and language will be changed
Language will be changed after device factory reset also