# ADB command toggles don't keep activities developer options setting but it has no real effect

Tags: android, adb

As the title says, if I issue the following command

```
adb shell settings put global always_finish_activities 1
```

if I go to Developer Options, I can see that the toggle as changed from OFF to ON. Also, `adb shell settings get global always_finish_activities` outputs `1`

The problem is that, although the setting has been turned ON, in fact, don't keep activities isn't doing what it is expected.

I only have the launcher and Chrome running and after I issue the ADB command, this is the stack that I have

[image]

On the other hand, if I do the same test and manually go to Developer Options settings and manually toggle the setting, this is the stack

[image]

Any idea how to bypass this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Don't keep activities means when an activity is stopped and a new one is started (or the process is sent to back) the framework will destroy all references to the activity (provided nobody keeps its reference). Print a log.d statement in `onDestroy()` in your activity and observe how when you navigate to another activity, the first one is destroyed. That's what the flag does ("not keeping activities in the back of the stack, just destroying them, ensuring that if you return, onCreate will have to be called again).

Comment: Thanks. I know what the flag does. The problem is, if I issue the command by adb, although the setting visually changes it does not actually do the same as going to the settings screen and click on the setting. I want to achieve the same but issuing the adb command.

Comment: You're correct; I was able to reproduce this; it appears to be a bug. I suggest you try the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and file a bug, because the moment you manually touch the setting, I can see in the log all the stack of activities being killed, but not if you do it via ADB. Good finding.